# Dividing a line/curve into certain number of points and extract the co-ordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, predict

I have a dataframe of a plot, which looks like this: [image]

Here are the coordinates of this plot:

```
x <- ( -9.736384, -8.113654, -6.490923, -4.868192, -3.245462, -1.622731,  0.000000,  1.622731,  3.245462,  4.868193,  6.490923,  8.113654,  9.736385)
y <- (1.119308090, 0.726472514, 0.423722058, 0.205458581, 0.066083942, 0.000000000, 0.001608615, 0.065311644, 0.185510949, 0.356608386, 0.573005817, 0.829105098, 1.119308090)

df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

Plot:

```
c <- ggplot(data =  df) + geom_line(aes(x = df$x, y = df$y), colour = "red", size = 0.5)
h <- c + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
ggplotly(h)
```

I want to increase the number of coordinate points of this curve for e.g. here there are 13 points, I want to divide this curve into say 80 equal parts and extract both x and y coordinates of that.

My attempt:

```
x <- seq(from = df[1,1], to = tail(df,1)[,1], length.out = 80)
```

This divides the x-coordinates into equal 80 parts.

Now, how do I predict the corresponding y coordinates of this plot?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `approx` to carry out a linear interpolation:

```r
df2 <- approx(df$x, df$y, seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length.out = 80))
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
```

[image]

Or a smoothed interpolation using `spline`:

```r
df3 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$x, df$y, 80))
ggplot(df3, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
```

[image]

And if you want a function that will give you the interpolated value of `y` for any given `x`, you can use `approxfun`:

```r
estimate <- approxfun(df$x, df$y)
```

So now the function `estimate` will do the job for you:

```r
estimate(-5)
#> [1] 0.2231873
```

Comment: Which one is better 'approx' or 'spline'? In this case, when I use 'spline', some predicted y values which I am getting are negative. But, 'approx' seems to be working better.

Comment: @kolas0202 it depends on what you want it for. `spline` will give you a nice smooth curve, but won't necessarily include the exact x, y, points you put into it. `approx` will definitely include your points, but effectively just tells you the x, y co-ordinates at any point on the straight lines joining your points. Which is better depends on the use case.